# Arranging absolute positioned elements symmetrically

Tags: html, css

I have been making a selection menu for my users under the search, For every one of selection button i have div:

```
    <div class="statbox">
        <select class="selectbox" id="stattrak">
            <option value="any"></option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
        <label class="stattext" for="stattrak">StatTrak™ <b class="caret_left">&#9654;</b></label>
```

and its style:

```
.statbox {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4.5%;
  top: 75px;
}
#stattrak {
  height: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}
.stattext {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

So as you see the div itself has absolute position, then there is text label `float:left` is used so it can be on the left side of box, and
`#stattrak` itself which is `<select>` element is following it's parent element's positions.

But i have multiple selection options, and i want them to be aligned properly in every y and x dimension. Please see the [code result](https://jsfiddle.net/xLxcbkgd/1/embedded/result/).

If you look at code from 1280x800 resolution, it should look very fine, but when you scale it down selection boxes overlap each other, and it looks asymmetrical when it's in higher dimension:

Higher resolution:

[image]

The parent of these element is `mover` div container, with the style:

```
.mover {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 61%;
}
```

It centers itself automatically.

I have also tried using `display: inline-block;` method, i tried it on two elements, one of them should have been left and second center, the style rule was: '.statbox { display: inline-block; margin-right: 60%; margin-top: 15px; }` and on second container that should be centered: .conbox { display: inline-block; margin-right: 60%; margin-top: 15px; }. And as you see conbox [messed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkwc3.png).

## The design:

There are 3 `<select>` elements in first row, one should be left, second center and third right.

in second row, there are 2 elements, one should be left second right.

and while this is happening what i tried was that these elements would be aligned exactly and symmetrically on left, center and right.

---

I have tried `float: ;` option but couldn't work as i needed it, what may the problem be? does float option work? if not then what's the best way to keep the items aligned with symmetrical differences? I don't need them to be absolute positioned if there's any better way, Thanks! ( [JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLxcbkgd/1/) )

I will be very thankful if you give final conclusion in jsfiddle.

Comment: Hi,  can u send me how it should look?

Comment: whn scaling to mobile width, all input boxes should come one by one below?

Comment: @Logeshwaran Hello, like the result, so i want first container to be more left, second in middle and third more to right, on second row i need one to be left and second right. When scaling i could use media queries so they can be vertically aligned one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

absolute positioned elements are removed from the document flow, this means they cannot be positioned symetrically using rules like float, you could position a parent div absolute and have the elements within positioned relative instead:

```
<div class="parent">
     <div class="statbox">
        <select class="selectbox" id="stattrak">
            <option value="any"></option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
        <label class="stattext" for="stattrak">StatTrak™ <b class="caret_left">&#9654;</b></label>
     </div>
     <div class="statbox">
        <select class="selectbox" id="stattrak">
            <option value="any"></option>
            <option value="true">Yes</option>
            <option value="false">No</option>
        </select>
        <label class="stattext" for="stattrak">StatTrak™ <b class="caret_left">&#9654;</b></label>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 4.5%;
  top: 75px;
}

.statbox {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
#stattrak {
  height: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: white;
}
.stattext {
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the parent of the statbox is `mover` which aligns everything in middle, it is not absolute positioned, can you give edit my jsfiddle so i can know how to edit all elements correctly? because i need some to be in center too, Thanks a lot!

Comment: you could wrap all the statboxes within mover in an extra div which is positioned absolute, why do you need to position them absolute anyway?

Comment: I don't need them to be positioned in absolute if there's any better way of doing it, also i have different div containers with different classes, should i make new containers for each one? @Alan Sutherland

Comment: I'd avoid using position absolute unless you have to position an element on top of another, it means the elements will not respect the bounds of others objects and you'll get overlapping, it makes responsive design especially difficult. So position the statboxes relative and float them left, or my preference would be display: inline-block; vertical: top; I find that to be more bulletproof than floats

Comment: Should i add these stylesheets to only div containers themselves?

Comment: by stylesheets do you meant the style rules? stylesheets refers to the entire css document, you should apply the float:left/display: inline-block rules only to the statboxes

Comment: Yes i meant style rules, sorry i'm kind of new to front end development.

Comment: Does `display: inline-block` center element in div?

Comment: Hello i tried it on two elements, one of them should have been left and second center, the style rule was: '.statbox { display: inline-block; margin-right: 60%; margin-top: 15px; }` and on second container that should be centered: `.conbox { display: inline-block; margin-right: 60%; margin-top: 15px; }`. And as you see `conbox` messed up: http://i.imgur.com/Nevu7TP.png

Comment: no worries I was very confused by css when I first started a few years back, you don't need the margin-right, display inline-block will position them all next to each othe, it doesnt center them, for that you could use display: block; margin: 0 auto;

Comment: if you feel like I've answered your question I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer ;)

Comment: Thank's a lot! I also used translatex on parent element to center it.

Comment: thanks :) use display: block; margin: 0 auto; instead of translate-x

Comment: i have tried it and it didn't seem to work, what's wrong with translate-x?

Comment: does the element also have float left on it still? that will stop it centering, translate is similar to using absolute positioning, dont use it unless you have to, positioning should be simple, things click in to place you shouldnt have to force them

Comment: nope i didn't have used it, i have this: `.mover2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%)
}`

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee that you'll face more cross-browser/responsive bugs with that styling. Using `position:relative; display: block; float: none; margin: 0 auto;` is way more bulletproof.